# Python - Remove ID Rows if Value does not exist in a given date diff (days)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Provided ID, Indicator and Datediff row, how can I remove any IDs that do NOT have an Indicator of Y that is 28 days or before according to row Datediff? I appreciate any help - thank you!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 113, 114, 114, 115,
                                                                 115],
                   'Indicator':['N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y',
                                                         'N', 'Y', 'N'],
                   'Dateddiff': [0, 10, 34, 0, 0, 28, 29, 0, 28, 30, 34]})
```

Input

```
ID   Indicator Datediff
111  N         0
111  Y         10
111  N         34
112  N         0
112  N         0
112  Y         28
113  Y         29  
114  Y         0
114  N         28
115  Y         30
115  N         34
```

Output

```
ID   Indicator Datediff
111  N         0
111  Y         10
111  N         34
112  N         0
112  N         0
112  Y         28 
114  Y         0
114  N         28
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean (w/o the double negative)?  One row with `N` and `34` is kept (ID 111), while another with `N` and `34` is omitted (ID 115).  It is also unclear what `Dateddiff` means, aka which day counts are "before"?

Comment: So there is another column where it shows dates. The datediff column is simply the number of days from the initial date. Essentially, I want to only keep the IDs that have had a Y on or before 28 (datediff). If a Y was found that was after 28 days, then the entire ID rows should be removed. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df_final = df[~(df.Indicator.eq('Y') 
                & df.Dateddiff.gt(28)).groupby(df.ID).transform('any')]

Out[37]:
    ID Indicator  Dateddiff
0  111         N          0
1  111         Y         10
2  111         N         34
3  112         N          0
4  112         N          0
5  112         Y         28
7  114         Y          0
8  114         N         28
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the further explanation.  You can find the IDs where the indicator is "Y" and the Dateddiff > 28.  You can then remove those IDs by reversing (`~`) `.isin()`:

```
bad_ids = df['ID'][(df['Indicator'] == 'Y') & (df['Dateddiff'] > 28)]
df = df[~df['ID'].isin(bad_ids)]
```

Output:

```
    ID Indicator  Dateddiff
0  111         N          0
1  111         Y         10
2  111         N         34
3  112         N          0
4  112         N          0
5  112         Y         28
7  114         Y          0
8  114         N         28
```